# site-packages directory not found after installing pip3 with apt-get in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: debian, python3, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed python 3 and `pip` into in Windows System for Linux shell, but it appears I have to find and specify `site-packages` directory manually if I want to run any python package executables. The packages I wanted to use were [cheat](https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat) and [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux-python.html), but the problem is the same for any package.

My chain of commands was:

- install WSL - Ubuntu 18.04
- `sudo apt-get update` (because `sudo apt-get install pip3` will not work
  on fresh installation)
- `sudo apt-get install pip3` (installs python too)
- `sudo pip3 install cheat`
- `cheat` not recognised as a command, while `python3` runs fine from
  `/usr/bin/python3`
- realise `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` must be on path
- in `~/.profile` add `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` to path 
  with `export PATH="$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages:PATH"`
- restart `~/.profile`

I there something I can change in the installation process so that I mustn't search for `site-packages` directory and add it to path manually?

UPDATE: proper call executed for pip was `sudo pip3 install cheat`. there is no plain `pip` on the system. calling `pip` results in error *Command 'pip' not found*.

Comment: Any comment accompanying a downvote will be highly appreciated

Comment: First of all, never use `sudo pip install`. By that, you save yourself a lot of future errors. Use `pip install --user` instead. Do it right now: got through `pip3 list` output, try to find packages you already installed (plus their dependencies), uninstall and reinstall them as user. By doing that, you will immediately notice the commands to become available because of the `PATH` changes you made.

Comment: If you, however, like to live on the edge and insist on `sudo pip install`ing, adjust the `PATH` correctly: check out the output of `pip3 show cheat | grep Location`, two segments up and descend into `bin` and add that directory to `PATH`.

Comment: @hoefling - exactly two things I was missing in the workflow! Do you care to put these comments as an answer, so that I can accept it? Installing as a user is indeed the missing step!

Comment: I have also noticed you're adding the wrong dir to `PATH`; suggested a fix in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. as suggested in the comments: don't use `sudo pip install` as you will get conflicts with the system package manager sooner or later. Always install python packages via `pip install --user`.
2. `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` shouldn't be on `PATH`, it's the directory containing python modules (python source code files), but no executables. You can check the path for user-installed executables with:

   ```
   $ python3 -m site --user-base | xargs -I {} echo {}/bin
   ```

   Most probably it's the `$HOME/.local/bin`. Add this one to `PATH` instead of `site-packages`. In your `.profile`/`.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` (whatever your OS specifies):

   ```
   PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
   export PATH
   ```

   Notice the `$PATH` instead of `PATH` in the path appending command.
   Now restart the terminal (or source the profile file) and check whether the installed executables are available:

   ```
   $ which eb
   $ eb --help
   ```

   etc.